grails: testing JSON response from a scaffolded controller
I am trying to test a simple grails Controller for JSON response.
I have tried both:

with simple scaffolded Controller (scaffolding = DomainClass)
exendding from RestfulController

controller has no other methods than the ones inherited / injected
I am doing something similar to what is explained here:
Grails Testing Support within example: src/test/groovy/demo/PersonControllerSpec.groovy
(from: Grails Documentation - 14 Testing)
(Except I don't redefine model
as variable model exists already)
I would expect, if I request index(), with right content-type, to receive a valid json response (possibly with an empty set)
Instead, I get a correct (status == 200) but empty response.
What am I doing wrong?
Code:
the Controller:
package bookstore

class CategoryController {

    static scaffold = Category

}

restful controller
package bookstore
import grails.rest.RestfulController

class RestFulCategoryController extends RestfulController<Category> {

    RestFulCategoryController() {
        super(Category)
    }

}

My test:
package bookstore

import grails.testing.web.controllers.ControllerUnitTest
import spock.lang.Specification
import grails.testing.gorm.DataTest
import org.grails.web.json.JSONException
import org.grails.web.converters.exceptions.ConverterException

class RestFulCategoryControllerSpec extends Specification implements ControllerUnitTest<RestFulCategoryController>, DataTest {

   void setupSpec() {
      mockDomain Category
   }
   void "test index action"() {
      setup:
      // should not be necessary, no visible change
      new Category(name:"category name", description: "category description").save()
      when:
      request.contentType = JSON_CONTENT_TYPE
      webRequest.actionName = 'index'
      def res = controller.index()

      then:
      status == 200
      res == null
      !model.keySet().contains('category')
      !model.keySet().contains('categories')
      model.keySet().contains('categoryCount')
      model.categoryCount == 0

      when:
      // throws exception
      println response.json

      then:
      ConverterException e = thrown()
      e.cause instanceof JSONException

   }
}

(the two tests scenarios are the same, and give very same results. second test just points to RestFulCategoryController)
